# Scripts to check if jboss started up correctly

Tags: jboss, scripting

Currently I have a script that starts up a jboss instance on four different servers. The script isn't optimized because currently it scans the jboss log for the key word "Started in: " and assumes everything is fine. However, we ran into a problem where sometimes the jboss doesn't connect to our LDAP and it still says "Started in: " in the logs and the scripts wrongly assumes the jboss started up correctly. So my question is what is a better way to see if the jboss started up correctly? It doesn't have to be limited to analyzing the logs if there are other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a statuspage to your server with the text "OK" and use wget from a script:

```
wget -O - http://<domain>:<port>/statuspage.html | grep OK
```

For JBoss you can use a modified version of the welcome-content or you can put a ROOT.war folder in the deployments folder which contains the statuspage.html file and a WEB-INF folder with a jboss-web.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

In this last case you also have to disable the welcome content in the standalone.xml or domain.xml:

```
 <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
```

Finally create an empty file in the deployments folder with the name:

```
ROOT.war.dodeploy
```